# How to insert selected data to table 2 using button and delete data from table 1?

Tags: mysql, visual-studio, module

can someone help me how to insert selected data from table1 (listview in vb form) to table2 and delete the data from table1 after inserted using button. I use visual studio and mysql for database. The delete portion is already working, the only problem is how I'm gonna transfer selected data coz its not working. I've been trying to figure out but I really don't know. Your help is very appreciated.
Ps.I also use module for this.
This is my code. Please also refer to the picture attached.

```vb
  If rs.State <> 0 Then rs.Close()
                Dim cmd As String = "INSERT * INTO completed_item"
                cmd = "SELECT * from sale_transactions WHERE id=" & ListView1.SelectedItems(0).Text
                rs.Open("DELETE FROM sale_transactions WHERE id=" & ListView1.SelectedItems(0).Text, con, 2, 3)
 End If
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qzApo.png)

Comment: You must execute 2 queries. `INSERT .. SELECT` then `DELETE`. And use connection.execute for these queries, not rs.open.

Comment: If ListView1.SelectedItems.Count <> 0 Then
 If MsgBox("Are you sure order is recieved?", vbYesNo + MsgBoxStyle.Question, "Please Confirm") = vbYes Then
 If rs.State <> 0 Then rs.Close()
Dim cmd As String = "INSERT * INTO completed_item" cmd = "SELECT * from sale_transactions WHERE id=" & ListView1.SelectedItems(0).Text

                rs.Open("DELETE FROM sale_transactions WHERE id=" & ListView1.SelectedItems(0).Text, con, 2, 3)
            End If
        Else
            MsgBox("Please select item first!", vbInformation, "Removing")
        End If

Comment: How to execute queries?

Comment: Do you use ADO? OLEDB? else? For example, for ADO see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ado/reference/ado-api/execute-requery-and-clear-methods-example-vb?view=sql-server-ver15

Comment: I use ADODB. Here is my module.

Comment: Module Module1
Public rs As New ADODB.Recordset
Public con As New ADODB.Connection
        Public Sub connectDB()
            Try
            con.Open("Driver={MySQL ODBC 3.51 Driver};" _
                     & "Server=localhost;" _
                     & "Database=final_examm;" _
                     & "User=root;" _
                     & "Password=admin;" _
                     & "Option=3;")
            Catch ex As Exception
                MsgBox(ex.Message, vbInformation)
            End Try
        End Sub
    End Module

Comment: Heres the picture for module database, hope it will help. https://drive.google.com/file/d/17ka4VumnE96pVDda3QR4t3mbVA8EZfRq/view?usp=drivesdk

Comment: Heres my code for the insert and delete. But only delete works. The insert or transferring data to table 2 is my problem.  https://drive.google.com/file/d/17yzd1kXgvGiILwcpxj342qqzyl2y5bPA/view?usp=drivesdk

Comment: Please help i badly need ur response. 

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.